# py2neo - UnicodeEncodeError in query

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, neo4j, py2neo

I'm getting am error when querying neo4j using py2neo, and cant seem to solve it. My code:

```
data, metadata = cypher.execute(self._db, 'START s=node:pages(title="%s") MATCH (s)-[r]->(n) RETURN n.title' % topic)
```

And the error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/cypher.py", line 50, in execute
    results = query.execute(**params or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 1011, in execute
    return CypherResults(self._execute(**params))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 1053, in __init__
    self._data = [record(*_hydrated(row)) for row in content["data"]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 178, in _hydrated
    return type(data)([_hydrated(datum) for datum in data])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/neo4j.py", line 177, in _hydrated
    elif is_collection(data):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py2neo/util.py", line 134, in is_collection
    hasattr(None, obj)
None: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any clues?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be a bug in py2neo triggered by an unexpected byte sequence or character set in the query result data. Are you able to elaborate on the data you would expect this to return and whether you are using UTF-8?

Comment: I am using UTF-8. Also, I noticed this problem occurs with version 1.6 of py2neo, but not 1.5.1.

Comment: I would suggest adding an extra except UnicodeEncodeError (returning False) to your is_collection method in util.py.

Comment: This issue has been raised in GitHub: https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there's a non-ASCII byte in `topic`, and that's probably what's causing it. If you're having that issue, you could probably try

```
data, metadata = cypher.execute(self._db, u'START s=node:pages(title="%s") MATCH (s)-[r]->(n) RETURN n.title' % topic)
```

And that might actually solve your problem. (I'd just comment with this, but I can't, sorry.) If that doesn't work, try:

```
(u'STATE s=node:...' ... % topic.decode('utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
```

That would do it.